# OpenCL - Can't modify values

Tags: c++, struct, kernel, buffer, opencl

My Problem is, that I can't modify values in my kernel.

This is the code that does not work:

1st: the kernel:

```
__kernel void GetCellIndex(__global Particle* particles) {
    int globalID = get_global_id(0);
    particles[globalID].position.x = globalID;
};
```

2nd: the struct used in the kernel:

```
typedef struct _Particle
{
    float3 position;
}Particle;
```

3rd: the pushing from CPU to GPU:

```
(Particle*) particles = (Particle*)malloc(sizeof(Particle)*200);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    particles[i].position.x = 5f;
}

cl_mem cl_Particles = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
    CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(Particle)*maxParticle, &particles[0], NULL);



//init of kernel etc.



err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cl_Particles);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: setKernelArg 0 does not work!" << std::endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

4th: run the kernel:

```
size_t localItem = 1;
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, 0, &(size_t)200+1, &localItem, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: EnqueueNDRange does not work!" << std::endl;
}

err = clFlush(queue);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: Flush does not work: " << err << std::endl;
}

err = clFinish(queue);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: Finish does not work: " << err << std::endl;
}
```

5th: the used struct on the GPU:

```
typedef struct _Particle
{
    cl_float3 position;
}Particle;
```

6th: finally the reading of the buffer:

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, 200 * sizeof(Particle), particles, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

after this steps my kernel does not effect the values returned in clEnqueueReadBuffer...

Does anyone know why? what is the problem here

Comment: Are you getting an error in the read? If the kernel went Out of memory bounds thats the point where the error will popup. Also check that in your Host side you are using `cl_float3` to declare your `Particle`object. Otherwise you will be allocating a smaller memory than needed.

Comment: thanks for replying!

the reading does not throw an error.
and what do you mean with with "use cl_float3"? i use it in my declartion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem:

Change the malloc line to something like

```
particles = new Particles[200];
```

also write the data in a seperate step to the buffer (with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer(...)`)

and the rest should work just like this code above